# Stratified sampling in python

Tags: python, sample

I would like to sample a dataframe base in python. This sample has to be stratified by specific variables.
I tried sklearn.cross_validation but the problem is that you can stratify with only one variable, and I need to stritify my population according to several variables.

So what I am looking for is the equivalent of proc survey, (strata instruction in SAS) or svydesign(in R).
Is this function exist in python ?

I found on this page the function stratified_samples
https://gist.github.com/spacelis/6088623
but there is no documentation or example of use and it is very hard to understand how you enter your stratified variable.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but for the benefit of those who arrived here from search:

There is a relatively new package in Python called `samplics`. This is an equivalent to the `survey` library in R. I am not experienced in SAS, though I imagine it should cover that too.

`samplics` is built to cover many aspects of complex survey design, including sampling, weighting and estimation. There is an example of sampling by locality on the [github page](https://github.com/samplics-org/samplics).

Other packages of interest (though documentation is slightly sparse):

- [Quantipy](https://github.com/Quantipy/quantipy/tree/staging-develop)
- [PandaSurvey](https://github.com/InContextSolutions/PandaSurvey)